# Compressing 5 Bytes into 4 Bytes

Tags: binary, endianness, bit-shift, bcd

I am trying to understand more about BCD, packed/unpacked byte arrays and byte shifting, in this picture I made an example of the instructions which I am unsure about, an array of 5 bytes is being compressed or packed into an array of 4 bytes, and vice versa. It converts `0x93, 0x87, 0xE3, 0xC3, 0x17` into `0xBC, 0x3C, 0x61, 0xD3`.Can anyone tell me if there is a generalized term for the method being used or is there decent documentations somewhere about this method or similar?
[image]

Many thanks